# Facebook IOS SDK not sharing to friends news feed

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api, ios7

I have a the Facebook sdk installed on an app that i am developing, however when i make the post it only shows up on my specific wall or news feed, my friends cannot see the post. What do i need to do in order to allow the post i make from my app to visible to my friends as well, not just my wall.

```
 // NOTE: pre-filling fields associated with Facebook posts,
// unless the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow of your app,
// can be against the Platform policies: https://developers.facebook.com/policy

NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:headline.text forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"picture"];




[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *FBerror)
 {
     if (FBerror)
     {
         //showing an alert for failure
         NSLog(@"failed to post to facebook");

     }
     else
     {
         //showing an alert for success
         NSLog(@"facebook upload successful");

         profileViewController *profile = [[profileViewController alloc]init];
         profile.author_name = username;
         profile.previous = @"sidemenu";
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];
     }
 }];
```

}